# Dynamic object key is taking only last value from for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have initialized an empty object in which I am dynamically creating a key and inserting values into it inside for loop.But here issue is its only taking the last value.

Why is it happening so, any correction do I need here.

```js
const obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  obj['arr'] = [];
  obj['arr'].push(i);
}

console.log(obj['arr']);

//    OUTPUT = [4]
```

Comment: Because you are initializing `obj['arr'] = []` everytime before you push to the array. So you are pushing the element to an empty array in each iteration.

Comment: Can you mention what's your expected output to understand what error you made?

Answer (score 2):

As already said, you are creating a new array each time so only the last push is saved.

You can fix this very easily with the nice `??=` [Nullish_coalescing_assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) which will assign a new array if one does not already exists

```js
const obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  obj['arr'] ??= [];
  obj['arr'].push(i);
}

console.log(obj['arr']);
```

It is of course only interesting in more complex object loops but very useful.

If you have a simple loop then

```js
const obj = { "arr":[] };

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  obj['arr'].push(i);
}

console.log(obj['arr']);
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@mamun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7461381/mamun) mentioned, you are reassigning `obj['arr']` in each iteration.

Instead, do this:

```
const obj = {};
obj['arr'] = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  obj["arr"].push(i);
}

console.log(obj["arr"]);
```